# Filter array containing only specific word

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, regex, string

I have a list of array. I want to get the items that start with "tar" and number followed by it

```
var array = ["dataseqno", "yrsno", "tar01", "tar02", "tar03", "tar04", "tar05", "tar06", "tar07", "tar08", "tar09", "tar10", "tar11", "tar12", "status"]
```

I will do the loop to this array and check using regex. This is the regex I have tried. But I couldnot solve number followed by 'tar'.

```
.match(/^tar+\[0-9]/)
```

Comment: @CertainPerformance edited. thank you

Comment: How about `Array#filter` ?

Comment: Try `^tar[0-9]+`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `filter()` on the array, and change your regex to `^tar[0-9]+` like so:

```js
var array = ["dataseqno", "yrsno", "tar01", "tar02", "tar03", "tar04", "tar05", "tar06", "tar07", "tar08", "tar09", "tar10", "tar11", "tar12", "status"];

var match = array.filter(str => str.match(/^tar[0-9]+/));

console.log(match);
```

This checks if the element starts with `tar` at the start of the string, then contains any digits afterwards.

---

Breakdown of the regex, character by character:

```
^
```

Match the start of the string

```
tar
```

Match the string `tar`

```
[0-9]
```

Match any characters in the character set 0-9 (will match `0`, `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, `5`, `6`, `7`, `8`, `9`)

```
+
```

Match one or more of the previous selector

Answer (score 4):

It will filter the array on the basis of regex which basically finds the word tar and checks if it is followed by a number

```js
var array = ["dataseqno", "yrsno", "tar01", "tar02", "tar03", "tar04", "tar05", "tar06", "tar07", "tar08", "tar09", "tar10", "tar11", "tar12", "status"]
console.log(array.filter((e)=>e.match(/^tar[0-9]+/)));
```

Comment: Even better: you can change it to a one-liner: `array.filter(e => e.match(/^tar[0-9]+/));` by using implicit return of the arrow function ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
let array = ["dataseqno", "yrsno", "tar01", "tar02", "tar03", "tar04", "tar05", "tar06", "tar07", "tar08", "tar09", "tar10", "tar11", "tar12", "status"]

const patt = new RegExp("tar+[0-9]");

let result = array.filter( x => patt.test(x) )

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you have asked, have tried to simulate. Please try. Thnx

```js
var names = ["dataseqno", "yrsno", "tar01", "tar02", "tar03", "tar04", "tar05", "tar06", "tar07", "tar08", "tar09", "tar10", "tar11", "tar12", "status"]

// Filter names
var filteredNames = 
  $.grep(names, function(v) {
    if(v.match(/^tar+\d{1,}/)){
      return v;
    }
    
 });
// show to console
$.each(filteredNames, function( i, val ) {
  console.log(val);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```